# Where should Tableau questions that don't involve writing code be asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Until earlier today, Stack Overflow had [quite a collection of [tableau] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableau), a large number of which were off-topic there.  Now the tag has been [renamed to [tableau-api] to emphasize that only *programming* questions about Tableau belong on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399672/208273):

> Questions about *using* Tableau are off-topic here. It is a data visualization tool, and unrelated to programming.

Where should these sorts of non-programming Tableau questions ([one example: "Changing the X axis header title"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844981/changing-the-x-axis-header-title-tableau)) be posted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is [Data Science.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), which has [100 posts containing "tableau"](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=tableau) and a [[tableau] tag with 31 questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tableau).  Additionally, a [post on that site's meta](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17) concludes that visualization (what Tableau does) is an integral part of data science.

Other places I looked, but don't seem correct:

- WebApps.SE has no positively voted Tableau questions.
- Stats.SE has a few questions *involving* tableau, but it's mostly incidental to the question in almost all of them.

Comment: I keep wishing that there would be more of a Tableau community on StackExchange because the experience in Tableau's own forums is a bit lacking. There are also plenty of "Tableau server management" questions that don't seem like they have a home on SE currently, for example diagnosing problems with failed extracts and the like. I think the best/easiest solution is probably to just keep Tableau on-topic for StackOverflow.